# Get image url in Meteor method

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor, collectionfs

I cannot seem to find any documentation that will explain how I can get the `filename` and `filepath` of an uploaded collectionFS image into my meteor method.

I am able to get the image URL on the client side no problem using `helpers`, but I cannot seem to figure out how I can send the filename and filepath of the attached image to my method.

**Method JS**

```
Meteor.methods({
addQuote: function(data) {
  check(data, Object);

  var attachments = [];
  var html = html;

  // need to get the filename and filepath from collectionFS
  // I would then have the data go here
  attachments.push({filename: , filePath: }); 

  this.unblock();

  var email = {
    from:    data.contactEmail,
    to:      Meteor.settings.contactForm.emailTo,
    subject: Meteor.settings.contactForm.quoteSubject,
    html:    html,
    attachmentOptions: attachments
  };

  EmailAtt.send(email);
}
});
```

**Controller JS**

```
        function ($scope, $reactive, $meteor) {
          $reactive(this).attach($scope);

          this.user = {};


          this.helpers({
            images: () => {
              return Images.find({});
            }
          });

          this.subscribe('images');

          this.addNewSubscriber = function() {


            // Uploads the Image to Collection
            if(File.length > 0) {
              Images.insert(this.user.contactAttachment);
              console.log(this.user.contactAttachment);
            }

            // This is the variable I use to push to my method
            // I image I need to push the filename and filepath also
            // I am unsure how to access that information in the controller.
            var data = ({
              contactEmail: this.user.contactEmail,
              contactName: this.user.contactName,
              contactPhone: this.user.contactPhone,
              contactMessage: this.user.contactMessage
            });

            // This will push the data to my meteor method "addQuote"
            $meteor.call('addQuote', data).then(
              function(data){
              // Show Success
              },
              function(err) {
              // Show Error
              }
            );
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the insert callback to get this informations:

```
Images.insert(fsFile, function (error, fileObj) 
{
      if (error) console.log(error);
      else 
      {
            console.log(fileObj);
             //Use fileObj.url({brokenIsFine: true}); to get the url
      }                           
});
```